# External media query for CSS not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've been playing with using different CSS files, for different browser sizes (to make the code cleaner and easier to tweak). This works fine in Firefox, but not in IE Edge or Chrome:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="./css/style.css" /> <!-- common css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 767px)" href="./css/smaller-
screen.css" />
```

I also tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-device-width: 767px)" href="./css/smaller-screen.css" />
```

As a test, I put this in the **smaller-screen.css** file:

```
body {
    min-width: 400px;
    background: red;
}
```

My HTML is pretty simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Chambres D'hotes New</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="./css/style.css" /> <!-- common css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-device-width: 767px)" href="./css/smaller-screen.css" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    content here

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you just tried `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`?

Comment: Unless your styles are completely different for different screen sizes, it makes more sense to bundle this in _one_ CSS resource, and use media queries in there.

Comment: @CBroe - yeah, they are quite different in looks (mainly around the header and sidebars). I used to put them all in one file, but it makes it tricky to tweak later on

Comment: @Pete - ah, that was it! Could you please add that as an answer? Can't believe I didn't try that!

Comment: You don't use `device-width` in media queries. You use `width`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with just `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 767px)" href="./css/smaller-screen.css" />
```

[More information about media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use this

```
    @media (max-width:767px){
        body {
            min-width: 400px;
            background: red;
        }
    }
```

This media query will work properly

Or you can use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 767px)" href="./css/smaller-screen.css" />
```

Comment: This doesn't answer question.

Comment: @shahid mohammad , thanks for the reply. I'm already aware of how to do that - I want to put an entire CSS file in a media query

Comment: This doesn't *understand* the question.

Comment: I understood the question propelry, and i have added both possible answers.